# Getting web page is not responding in IE10

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5, internet-explorer-10, isapi

My web application is developed with classic ASP page, Java Applets and  VB script. It also communicates with ISAPI dll.In some machines My application is working fine in IE10.

In some other machines I am always getting webpage is not responding when running my application with IE 10, but when trying with IE 9 and 8 its working fine in the same machines. The other websites are working fine in IE 10.

I tried with following troubleshooting methods, but nothing is helped me.

1. I reset the IE settings .
2. I disabled all the Add ons.
3. I cleared the cache

Whether the problem is because of any windows updates missing? PLease show me a direction for this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have activeX controls? Are you sure that classic ASP is causing the freeze, and not Java?

Answer (score 0):

You have disabled friendly error messages, yes?